# Magento ecommerce: Can’t login to admin or add items to cart in Safari 5.0 on a Mac

Tags: magento, browser, cookies, safari, magento-1.5

I am dealing with a very particular issue on a newly built Magento ecommerce site (running version 1.5.1), [www.azaturechocolates.com](http://www.azaturechocolates.com).

My client is unable to login to the admin panel or add items to the shopping cart in Safari 5.0 (on a macbook machine).  However the site works fine for them in Firefox.

I have tested multiple Safari browsers (PC, Mac, Macbook, version 5.0, 5.1) and cannot replicate the issue, the site works well for me. The site also works fine for all other browsers, IE, FF, Chrome.

We checked the clients’ cookie settings and security settings and all seemed normal.  Also, we cleared the cache and cookies several times with same results.

Any ideas or suggestions on what could be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase session life time to few days. Issue can be dependence on different time zones. So try to make session life time as long as you can try, for experiment.

Hope it'll help.